# Apache-POI XSSFRichTextString bug

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

Calling `richText.getFontOfFormattingRun(index) throws a NullPointerException` if the first group of words is not formatted. Is this an Apache POI bug?

```
 XSSFRichTextString rt = (XSSFRichTextString) cell.getRichStringCellValue ();
 if (rt.numFormattingRuns () > 0)
 {
    content = "";
    for (int t = 0; t < rt.numFormattingRuns (); t++)
    {
      if(rt.getFontOfFormattingRun (t) != null)
        //handle the content based on the formatting
```

Comment: please provide code details

Comment: What POI version are you using?
I've checked 3.13 and all work good. Please provide example strings to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I was using an older version of Apache poi.

Comment: Can you please tell us which version you were using that cause the exception?